# Change strings with different format to dates with the same format in a dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a dataframe which looks like this (it has thounds of date rows like this, ranging from years 18xx until 2019)

```
                date
1   25 February 1987
2     20 August 1974
3     9 October 1984
4          16-Oct-63
5         13-11-1961
6           03/23/87
7         01.01.1995
8      February 1988
9               1988
10 20050101-20051231
```

I need to change the date column to one date-format (eg.: YYYY-MM-DD, or any other). 
Since there are just some Year values as for ID 9, I also have to autofill them. This should always lead to the last day of the particular year. If it ist like ID 8 a month and a year, it should always fill the last day of the particular month (and check if it was a leap year, like it was in 1988 and return in this case something like 1988-02-29). If it is a timeframe like in the last row, it should always cut off the first part and change it to the 31st of December of the given year.
How can I do this?

I thought about using the lubridate package or the anytime package. With lubridate and parse_date or parse_date_time. This even works, but it always fills the missing values for days to the first day of a month and not the last.

```
library(lubridate)

date <- c("25 February 1987", "20 August 1974", "9 October 1984", "16-Oct-63", "13-11-1961", "03/23/87", "01.01.1995",
          "February 1988", "1988", "20050101-20051231")

df <- as.data.frame(date)

parse_date(df$date)

parse_date_time(x = df$date,
                orders = c("d m y", "d B Y", "d/m/Y","B Y", "Y", "m/d/y",
                           "Ymd-Ymd"),
                locale = "eng")
```

My actual results

```
(parse_date(df$date)): 

 [1] "1987-02-25 UTC" "1974-08-20 UTC" "1984-10-09 UTC" "2019-10-16 UTC" "2019-11-13 UTC" "1987-03-23 UTC" "1995-01-01 UTC"
 [8] "1988-02-01 UTC" "1988-01-01 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC"
```

For the parse_date_time I acutally get an error, due to the last orders "Ymd-Ymd" (If I just test: `parse_date("20050101-20051231") it results in "2005-12-31 UTC"`, which I really want to have!)

Comment: `parse_date_time(date, c("dmY", "ymd", "dmy", "mdy", "Y"))`  The last one is a format needs splitting as it won't be recognized as a date format output

Comment: I couldn't find the `parse_date(df$date)#`
Error in parse_date(df$date) : could not find function "parse_date" from `lubridate`

Comment: Oh, sorry. parse_date(df$date) is from package "parsedate"

Comment: thanks, what is your expected output.  are you saying that `parse_date` gives correct results?

Comment: For `parse_date`, some dates are wrong `"16-Oct-63"`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lubridate cheat sheet (https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf)
and by trial and error with dplyr :

```
df %>% 
        mutate(newdate = parse_date_time(x = date, orders = c("dmy", "mdy", "my", "y")) ) %>% 
        mutate(newdate2 = case_when(
                        newdate > today() ~ newdate - 100*365.25*24*3600,
                        is.na(newdate) ~ paste0(substr(x=date, start = 1, stop = 4), "-", 
                                                substr(x=date, start = 5, stop = 6), "-",
                                                substr(x=date, start = 7, stop = 8) )
                        %>%
                                parse_date_time(., orders = c("dmy", "mdy", "my", "y", "ymd")),
                        TRUE ~ newdate
        )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This is very close. Unfortunately, it still gives me the wrong output dates for some entries.

```
               date    newdate   newdate2
1   25 February 1987 1987-02-25 1987-02-25
2     20 August 1974 1974-08-20 1974-08-20
3     9 October 1984 1984-10-09 1984-10-09
4          16-Oct-63 2063-10-16 1963-10-16
5         13-11-1961 1961-11-13 1961-11-13
6           03/23/87 1987-03-23 1987-03-23
7         01.01.1995 1995-01-01 1995-01-01
8      February 1988 1988-02-19 1988-02-19
9               1988 1988-01-01 1988-01-01
10 20050101-20051231       <NA> 2005-01-01
```

But I need it like this:

```
               date    newdate   newdate2
1   25 February 1987 1987-02-25 1987-02-25
2     20 August 1974 1974-08-20 1974-08-20
3     9 October 1984 1984-10-09 1984-10-09
4          16-Oct-63 2063-10-16 1963-10-16
5         13-11-1961 1961-11-13 1961-11-13
6           03/23/87 1987-03-23 1987-03-23
7         01.01.1995 1995-01-01 1995-01-01
8      February 1988 1988-02-19 **1988-02-29**
9               1988 1988-01-01 **1988-12-31**
10 20050101-20051231       <NA> **2005-12-31**
```

This means: If I only have year and month: I need to enter the last day of the particular month and for February to consider leap years, like in the example row 8. If I just have a year, I need to change it to 31st of December of the given year. And if the entry looks like in row 10, I need to cut of the first part and just keep the 31st of December of the given year, but for this case, I already adjusted the part of your code:

```
is.na(newdate) ~ paste0(substr(x=date, start = 10, stop = 13), "-", 
                            substr(x=date, start = 14, stop = 15), "-",
                            substr(x=date, start = 16, stop = 17) )
```

Comment: I solved it now with regex and checked all different formats. But if you have better, and more easy solutions, feel free to post it. 
Thank you for your help. :-)